# Display only year from a date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, column-formatting

I want to import in a SharePoint list a column containing the "year". So, I have in the import column just a number, like "2020".

Then, I use the List to display is a custom React application that uses this list.

What kind of type should I put to the column? Date? Number?

If I put the number, it displays me with thousands separators `2 020` (in the default view). Even if this is not critical, as I display it in a custom application, I am not sure if the "number" is the best format for this column.
[image]
If I use as "date-time", I think the import will fail if I import only "2020".

Comment: Where it is showing thousands separator, in SharePoint default list view?

Comment: @GaneshSanap that is not critical, because finally I will display it in the react application as I want

Comment: Can you show us which API call are you using and what are the outputs you are getting for this number column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "Number" column for storing year in SharePoint list.

You can set "Use thousands operator" to "No" from column settings:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

1. For validations: you can use "Min" and "Max" options or column validation option in column settings.

Follow below steps to open modern experience column settings:

1. Go to SharePoint list view
2. Click on column name/header, select Column settings > Edit

   [image]
3. After clicking on Edit, you will see the column settings panel. Scroll down on panel, click on "More options". You will see "Use thousands operator" option under More options in column settings panel

Comment: how about validation and things like this? negative, decimal, too big to small

Comment: also, defalt value could be current date if I use a date...

Comment: You can use column validation settings for number column. You can set "Min" or "Max" values for number columns from column settings

Comment: I have no such an option "use thousands separator", I can display as "%" and specify the number of decimals

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: I use "SharePoint dans Microsoft 365" (fr)

Comment: updated the OP with picture

Comment: You are checking classic column settings page where the mentioned option is not available. Check updated answer to open modern experience column settings.

Comment: Hi @serge, did you try it? Is it working for you?

Comment: It seems your idea it not finished... Edit... and what? should we pass in another experience?

Comment: After clicking on Edit, you will see the column settings panel. Scroll down on panel, click on "More options". You will see "Use thousands operator" option under More options in column settings panel.

Comment: I see now, I thought you are talking about the List properties settings, but is about the list *view* properties, thanks